# Как расставлять запятые при вводном _более того_ в начале обособленного оборота?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Согласно правилу, присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже используются тире, точка, многоточие). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, и (‘и притом’), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только и др.

Некоторые студенты, в частности первокурсники, до сих пор не сдали зачет по физкультуре.

Вводное сочетание *более того* может ли быть в ряду этих слов? И в предложениях

*Студенты, более того первокурсники, уже сдали зачет по физкультуре.*

*Ему досталась большая часть картин, более того самые ценные.*

*более того первокурсники* и *более того самые ценные* - это уточнение или присоединение?

*Не зажимаю, более того в пробке могу принять правее или левее чтобы он не стоял за мной, а проехал между машинами.*

Здесь часть после запятой - это присоединительная конструкция?

И правильна ли пунктуации в этих предложениях, если учитывать правило об отсутствии запятой после вводного слова, открывающего обособленную конструкцию, и перед вводным словом, закрывающим такую конструкцию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайте внимание на метки, которые вы добавляете к вопросам.

Answer (score 2):

В процитированном правиле слова и сочетания, которые упомянуты как используемые для присоединения, отобраны совсем *не про принципу вводности*. Наоборот, в рассматриваемых присоединительных конструкциях они вводными не являются, хотя в другом контесте могут таковыми оказаться (напр. сочетание "в частности" во многих случаях бывает вводным). Выражение "более того" иногда можно сделать "не вводным":

> Он отобрал с десяток приглянувшихся грибов и более того покупать не
>   стал.

Но в вашем примере требуется обособление:

> Некоторые студенты, более того, первокурсники, уже...

иначе (без второй запятой) восприниматься выражение будет так, будто "первокурсники больше, чем студенты", что неестественно - у сочетания "более того" сильновыраженный "вводный" смысл, который легче отнести к высказыванию в целом (= скажу больше, обратите внимание, что не просто студенты). Для сравнения - вариант с более подходящим присоединительным выражением (здесь присоединено уточнение, что первокурсники являются *частным случаем* студентов):

> Некоторые студенты, в частности первокурсники, уже...